# ListBox in constructor

Tags: c#, listbox

I am doing an assignment for university and in it there is a class called Calculation which as part of the brief has the Calculation class with a ListBox in the constructor.
I am getting an error which says 'A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'AddStripForm.lstDisplay'
i'm not sure what this means in this context.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
namespace GUI_Calculator
{
    public partial class Calculation : Form
{
    AddStripForm addStrip = new AddStripForm();
    bool isModified = false;
    ListBox lstDisplay;
    ArrayList theCalcs;
    string filename = "";

    public Calculation(ListBox lb)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lb = lstDisplay;
        theCalcs = new ArrayList();
        theCalcs[0] = 0;
    }

    public void Add(CalcLine c1)
    {

    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        foreach(int n in theCalcs)
        {
            theCalcs[n] = null;
        }
        lstDisplay.Items.Clear();
    }

    public void Redisplay()
    {

    }

    public CalcLine Find(int n)
    {
        return (CalcLine)theCalcs[n];
    }

    public void Replace(CalcLine newCalc, int n)
    {
        isModified = true;
        theCalcs[n] = newCalc;
        Redisplay();
    }

    public void Insert(CalcLine newCalc, int n)
    {

    }

    public void Delete(int n)
    {
        foreach(int x in theCalcs)
        {
            if(Convert.ToInt32(theCalcs[x]) == n)
            {
                theCalcs[x] = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void SaveToFile(string filename)
    {

    }

    public void LoadFromFile(string filename)
    {

    }
}
}
```

There is the Calculation Class

```
 namespace GUI_Calculator
{
public partial class AddStripForm : Form
{
    Calculation calc = new Calculation(lstDisplay);

    public AddStripForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void txtValue_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {

            string newNum = txtValue.Text;

            if (txtValue.Text.StartsWith("+"))
            {
                lstDisplay.Items.Add(txtValue.Text);

            }
            else if (txtValue.Text.StartsWith("-"))
            {
                lstDisplay.Items.Add(txtValue.Text);
            }
            else if (txtValue.Text.StartsWith("*"))
            {
                lstDisplay.Items.Add(txtValue.Text);
            }
            else if (txtValue.Text.StartsWith("/"))
            {
                lstDisplay.Items.Add(txtValue.Text);
            }
            else if (txtValue.Text.StartsWith("="))
            {
                lstDisplay.Items.Add(txtValue.Text);
            }
        }
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstDisplay.SelectedItems.Clear();
    }
}
}
```

There is the AddStripForm Code

Comment: Can you please show the code?

Comment: 'public Calculation(ListBox lb)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lstDisplay = lb;
            theCalcs = new ArrayList();
            theCalcs[0] = 0;
        }'
that is the constructor for the Calculation Class.

Comment: when I reference the class in the AddStripForm(MainForm) this is the code
Calculation calc = new Calculation(lstDisplay);
that is where I get the error

Comment: `Calculation calc` is a field and when you try to initialize it with  `new Calculation(lstDisplay)` lstDisplay is not accessable because it is an instance variable, I think... That is as far as i can say without seeing any code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are using the `ListBox` which is an instance variable. Move the Calculation class initialization to the constructor as follows:

```
Calculation calc;

public AddStripForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    calc  = new Calculation(lstDisplay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the error with this code. The problem is that `LstDisplay` is an instance member but you try to access is by using TypeName, `AddStripForm.LstDisplay`. Instead, provide the value from the constructor.

```
public AddStripForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    calc = new Calculation(LstDisplay);
}
```

Code to replicate error

```
namespace StackOverFlow {

    public class AddStripForm : Form {
        public ListBox LstDisplay { get; set; }
    }

    public class Calculation {

        public Calculation(ListBox lb) {
        }
    }

    internal class Program {

        Calculation calc = new Calculation(AddStripForm.LstDisplay);

        private static void Main(string[] args) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that member variable lstDisplay is a member variable in the same class that member variable calc is in (AddStripForm) and that calc is being initialized and using the member variable lstDisplay before the class has fully constructed.

Assign calc in the constructor.

```
calc = new Calculation(lstDisplay);
```

Consider:

```
public class WontCompile
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c = a + b;
}

public class WillCompile
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    public WillCompile()
    {
        c = a + b;
    }
}
```